# Retrieving array from dictionary appears to result in a deep copy

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The following code adds an array to a dictionary. The array's first element is given a default value. Then, the array is looked up in the dictionary and a new value is assigned to the first element. Yet, upon looking up the array again in the dictionary, it still has the default value.

I've got around this by assigning the modified array back to the dictionary, but my concern is that the look-up and the re-write will result in the entire contents of the array being copied twice.

Is it possible to work with a reference to the array?

```
<% Option Explicit

    Function createArray

        Dim newArray(10)

        newArray(0) = "Hello"

        createArray = newArray

    End Function

    Dim myDictionary, myArray

    Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    myDictionary.Add "MyItem", createArray

    myArray = myDictionary("MyItem")

    Response.Write myArray(0) 'Hello

    myArray(0) = "World!"

    Response.Write myArray(0) 'World!

    myArray = myDictionary("MyItem")

    Response.Write myArray(0) 'Hello

    %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript (classic ASP), an array is NOT an object, so you also do not use the Set operator to copy an array.

It's only logical (in a VBScript kind of way) that the array gets copied by value, i.e. a deep copy.

As a quick reference I could only find [this comparison](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/arrays) between JScript and VBScript arrays. Citing:

> A VBScript array is:
>
> > multi-dimensional
> >      indexed by integer tuples
> >      dense
> >      not an object
>
> Whereas a JScript array is:
>
> > one dimensional.
> >      associative; JScript arrays are indexed by strings. Numeric indices are actually converted to strings internally.
> >      sparse: arr[1](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/arrays) = 123; arr[1000000] = 456; gives you a two-member array, not a million-member array.
> >      an object with properties and methods.

Comment: Its a value type then.